# Python changing parameter lists

Tags: python

I want to change the list items thats given as parameter.
For example

```
def method(list) :
    list = [1,2,3]
```

I want that any list given as parameter changes to [1,2,3].
So I get something like this:

```
>>> a =[4,5,6]
>>> method(a)
>>> a
[1,2,3]
```

Comment: Just for curiosity, why?

Comment: So always `return [1,2,3]` ?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name - it masks the builtin `list()` function. Same with the rest of [these](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html).

Comment: @fedorqui: `return [1, 2, 3]` won't work as you think.

Answer (score 3):

Use list slicing:

```
 def method(l):
     l[:]=[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following function.

```
def method(lst) :
    list_ = [1,2,3]
    return list_

a = [4,1,2]

a = method(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `list` as your own variable, as that masks the built-in function `list()`.

`list`s are passed by reference, but if you reassign something to the reference in a function's local scope, the reference will simply point to the new object. Instead, `return` the new object and then save a reference to it.

```
>>> def method(lst):
...     return [1, 2, 3]
...
>>> a = [4, 5, 6]
>>> a = method(a)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for list of any length.

```
def method(lst):
    lst[:] = [x+1 for x in range(len(lst))]
```